# Divs around a circular Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to put 5 div around a circle div, how can I achieve it ?

This is my code so far :

```css
.main{
 border: 2px dotted #000000;
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
}
.cirlce1{
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 border: 2px dotted #000000;
 border-radius: 50%;
 top: 50px;
}
.cirlce2{
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 border: 2px dotted #000000;
 border-radius: 50%;
 top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <div class="cirlce1"></div>
 <div class="cirlce2"></div>
</div>
```

I want my output to be like

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: well if the big circle size is static, try to set the smaller circle position to absolute

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the position of the small circles as `position: absolute;` and then play with `top`, `left`, `right` or `bottom` for placing them on the desired place.

I recommend you to use `%` for setting the position so it will be responsive, but in the case the big circle size is static you can just set the position with `px`.

```css
.main{
 border: 2px dotted #000000;
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
}
.cirlce1{
  position: absolute;
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 border: 2px dotted #000000;
 border-radius: 50%;
 top: 50%;
}
.cirlce2{
  position: absolute;
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 border: 2px dotted #000000;
 border-radius: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <div class="cirlce1"></div>
 <div class="cirlce2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: how to rotate it, like solar system animation

Answer (score 20):

The key is to position the small circles absolutely in relation to the big one.

You can then center them using `calc()`.

Finally a series of transforms is applied to each small circle, moving them to the outside edge, then rotating each one around the large circle by 1/5th of 360deg (72deg). If you're using a preprocessor such as SASS, this final step could be done using a loop.

```css
.main {
    position: relative;
    border: 2px dotted #000000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

.circle {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 25px);
    top: calc(50% - 25px);
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 2px dotted #000000;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translateX(250px);
}

.circle:nth-child(2) {
    transform: rotate(72deg) translateX(250px);
}

.circle:nth-child(3) {
    transform: rotate(144deg) translateX(250px);
}

.circle:nth-child(4) {
    transform: rotate(216deg) translateX(250px);
}

.circle:nth-child(5) {
    transform: rotate(288deg) translateX(250px);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Woah, nice one !

Comment: how to animate it like solar system rotate or you can say motion graphic @patrik kunka

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style type="text/css">
 .main{
  border: 2px dotted #000000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
.cirlce1{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 2px dotted #000000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50px;
  margin-top: 75px;
}
.cirlce2{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 2px dotted #000000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50px;
  margin-top: 240px;
}
.cirlce3{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 2px dotted #000000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 400px;
}
.cirlce4{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 2px dotted #000000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 750px;
  margin-left: 250px;
}
.cirlce5{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 2px dotted #000000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 450px;
  margin-top: -1200px;
}
</style>
<div class="main">
  <div class="cirlce1"></div>
  <div class="cirlce2"></div>
  <div class="cirlce3"></div>
  <div class="cirlce4"></div>
  <div class="cirlce5"></div>

</div>
```